# preg_replace for words containing space doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

it's not working for words containing spaces, it works for single words

if possible changing the words from array to bold

the real code

```
$_POST['descricao'] = "parede hidráulica: teste de parede hidráulica";

$palavras = array("/\bparede hidráulica cozinha\b/i",
"/\bparede área de serviço\b/i",
"/\bparede area de serviço\b/i",
"/\bparede hidraulica cozinha\b/i",
"/\bparede hidráulica\b/i",
"/\bparede hidraulica\b/i",
"/\bparede box\b/i",
"/\btorneira\b/i",
"/\bbancada\b/i",
"/\bsoleira\b/i",
"/\bbaguete\b/i",
"/\brodapé\b/i",
"/\brodape\b/i",
"/\bparede\b/i");

$maiusculas = array_map('mb_strtoupper', $palavras);
$maiusculas = str_ireplace('\b/i', '', $maiusculas);
$maiusculas = str_ireplace('/\b', '', $maiusculas);

$_POST['descricao'] = preg_replace($palavras, $maiusculas, $_POST['descricao'], 1);
```

output: PAREDE HIDRÁULICA: teste de PAREDE HIDRÁULICA

correct output: PAREDE HIDRÁULICA: teste de parede hidráulica

Comment: Try to change line 2 to `$arr = array("red apple", "green lemon");` (mind the quotes).

Comment: i need to change only the first match

Comment: i'm using quotes but i forgot to put it on my question.. its correct now but it doesn't work yet

Comment: Is that really your code? You seem to have pattern and replacement arrays mixed up.

Comment: no... it's an example code

Comment: Then please post actual running code (see http://sscce.org/).

Comment: i can't it's very complex and it's in other language

Comment: What's your example `$_POST['descricao']` look like?

Comment: i've edited my code.. take a look

Comment: What's your version of php ?

Comment: Exactly which output do you want?

Comment: output: PAREDE HIDRÁULICA: teste de parede hidráulica
no matter how many times the word repeats it need to change only first match.. it's like a title then i need to set it bold and uppercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was solved like this, i've changed my need and using this regex it matches with double words if the word is in uppercase

```
$_POST['descicao'] = 'UNITED STATES test';
$_POST['descricao'] = preg_replace("/\b([A-Z]{2,}(\s[A-Z]{2,})?)\b/", "<b>$1</b>"
```

output: `<b>UNITED STATES</b> test`

Answer (score 1):

First argument of [**preg_replace function**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is regex (or an array of regex).

I believe it should be:

```
$arr = array("/\bred apple\b/i", "/\bgreen lemon\b/i");
$arr2 = array("RED APPLE", "GREEN LEMON");

$repl = preg_replace($arr, $arr2, $string, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove the count argument at the end of this line:

```
$_POST['descricao'] = preg_replace($palavras, $maiusculas, $_POST['descricao']);
```

This would give you:

```
PAREDE HIDRáULICA: teste de PAREDE HIDRáULICA
```

instead of:

```
PAREDE HIDRáULICA: teste de parede hidráulica
```

However, your code is behaving exactly as expected.

If it doesn't suit you, you should provide us your expected output, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: yep.. but i need only the first match to be changed.. it would be like a title

Comment: not exactly i need the second occurence

PAREDE HIDRáULICA: teste de parede hidráulica
no matter how many times the same word appears it needs only change the first match for example output -> PAREDE HIDRÁULICA teste parede hidráulica parede hidráulica