# i need to copy and then rename the copy of a file if it already exists

Tags: php, file-upload, filenames, file-rename

need to copy and then rename the copy of a file if it already exists

```
$pastaTemp = $_FILES['imagem_principal']['tmp_name'];
$pastaUpload = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/casaunica/imagens/acabamentos/";
$arquivo = $pastaUpload . $_FILES['imagem_principal']['name']; //filename.jpg

if(!file_exists($pastaUpload. $_FILES['imagem_principal']['name'])){
      $arquivo = $pastaUpload . $_FILES['imagem_principal']['name'];
} else {
    $nome_arquivo = explode(".",$_FILES['imagem_principal']['name']);
       do {
          $para = $nome_arquivo[0]."_".$i.".".$nome_arquivo[1];
          $nome_novo = rename($arquivo, $pastaUpload . $para);
          $arquivo = $pastaUpload .$nome_novo;
          $i++; 
       } while(file_exists($pastaUpload.$_FILES['imagem_principal']['name']));
}
```

output: filename.jpg_1

it should be: filename_2.jpg

it can't replace the old file.. that's why i need to rename with a number
it doesn't need to be made in a loop but everytime that a file is uploaded

Comment: Looks like the explode isn't working the way you want it to

Comment: the explode works, maybe rename function is wrong or i should use another function

Comment: Have you tried echoing $para? That line seems like the most obvious root of the problem, though I can't see anything particularly wrong

Comment: i did and it's correct, i've changed do while for while and it works but it replaces the old file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, let me know if it works

**Function**

```
<?php
  function recursive_naming( $file, $i = 1 ) {
    $dirname    = dirname( $file ).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $filename   = pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
    $extension  = pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

    if ( !file_exists( $file ) ) {
      return $file;
    }
    $filename = preg_replace( '/_\d+$/', '', $filename );
    $file = $dirname.$filename."_".$i.".".$extension;
    $i++;
    return recursive_naming( $file, $i );
  }
?>
```

**Example:**

```
<?php
  $pastaTemp    = $_FILES['imagem_principal']['tmp_name'];
  $pastaUpload  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/casaunica/imagens/acabamentos/";
  $arquivo      = recursive_naming( $pastaUpload.$_FILES['imagem_principal']['name'] );
?>
```

It will output `filename_2.jpg` if `filename.jpg` exists, or `filename_3.jpg` if `filename_2.jpg` also exists, and so on...

Comment: can u help me with this??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796927/preg-replace-for-words-containing-space-doesnt-work